# Browse the web on a non-internet TV

Tags: hdtv, micro-pc, htpc

I'm looking for a way to display web content on non-internet capable TVs. Requirements are:

- HDMI output to the TV
- Built in WiFi or USB WiFi capability
- Simple for non-technical people to control, ideally no mouse/keyboard needed (a remote would be nice)
- Doesn't break the bank

Things I've tried so far and haven't worked:

- Generic Android TV stick: Too complicated and requires a kb/mouse
- Roku: The only browser in their channel store is $5/mo which is out of the question
- Amazon FireTV: Was able to find a real hacky way to get a browser on it, but it rendered content in a real bad way for no discernible reason

I'm considering a Raspberry Pi but again that's a little more tech intensive than I'd like, hopefully one of you have run into a device that meets these requirements. Finding a simple device that has Chrome/Firefox/whatever built in or available is proving to be more difficult than I thought.

Comment: Could you define "Doesn't break the bank"? That would seem like a lot of money, yet you say Roku at $5/mo is too much.

Comment: You could probably look at the intel compute stick.

Comment: @user3169 The hardware isn't going to need to do a lot but be a web browser that sits on a single page 99% of the time, so paying $100 for hardware is silly. And $5 a month for a web browser is equally silly. When I say doesn't break the bank I'm talking about the hardware itself in total, and I think $50 would be an upper limit for such a device

Comment: @StephenFischer If you have another PC (even an old laptop) that you can broadcast the picture from, you could get a Steam Link unit along with a mini remote kb/m (something like this: https://www.amazon.com/Rii-Wireless-Keyboard-mini-X1/dp/B00I5SW8MC). That's really all I can think of that's going to hit the functions you want at the $50 price point you're looking for. Everything else is going to be lackluster (Amazon Fire Stick = not enough power), more tech-intensive than you want (R.Pi), or too expensive (mini-PC, Intel Compute Stick).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much you want to spend I would say Raspberry Pi would be the way to go as you will be able to install a nice OS that could be tailored to what you are after, or if you would farther have a slightly easier system there are a number of Zotac mini PC’s that pack a lot of hardware in a tiny form factor.

As for the controller if you have a look about there are a number of different options such as small wireless touch pads that could be used or you could find something like a windows media controller and see if there are some tweaks to get it to control the PC.

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar thread a couple weeks ago and settled for this [Mini PC](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01M24W77N/ref=pe_3187911_189395841_TE_dp_1):

It's been great so far. I'm pushing 4k on it comfortably and it seems powerful enough for streaming and general web browsing. It's not great at multitasking as you can imagine for a small PC but it's been great for me so far!

Comment: (And i've been using this to control it: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/r.html?C=2F1HKFMSHK6AF&K=A1TZ5LCKJ3IV3M&R=7MQQLX7YLVRI&T=C&U=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.co.uk%2Fdp%2FB072LWZ3K4%2Fref%3Dpe_1909131_77697001_tnp_email_TE_AMZLdp_1&A=FOFFOTWGY5OL7T9EX7VRAOBZS2CA&H=SA0I2VT3EFVRV9N9IRRIJCSSV6UA&ref_=pe_1909131_77697001_tnp_email_TE_AMZLdp_1)

Answer (score 0):

Chromecast would fit the description.
I've gotten them for my non-technical parents and they use it all the time.
It's inexpensive and easy to 'cast' webpages or videos, etc from a phone/tablet to the device.

I personally built a HTPC/NAS device. But that's a little overkill for most needs